# Proof Verification: Consequence of Bertrand's Posulate and Sums of Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am currently self-studying number theory in high school, and came across this question:

> Assuming that for every integer $n>1$, there exists a prime number between $n$ and $2n$, prove that every positive integer can be written as a sum of distinct primes or $1$ more than a sum of distinct primes.

My attempt:

---

We use induction on $\Bbb N$.

Clearly, $1$ can be written simply as $1$, thus the conjecture is true for $1$. We assume that the conjecture is true for all numbers up to some $k\in \Bbb N$.

Now, we take $k+1$ and find out $\Bigl \lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \Bigl \rfloor.$ By Bertrand's Postulate, there must exist primes between $\Bigl \lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \Bigl \rfloor$ and $2\Bigl \lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \Bigl \rfloor$, where $2\Bigl \lfloor \frac{k+1}{2} \Bigl \rfloor \leq k+1.$ By the well-ordering principle, the set of primes has a least element, say $p$. We find out $(k+1)-p$.

Now by our induction hypothesis, the number $(k+1)-p$ can be written as the sum of distinct primes, none of them $p$ since $p>(k+1)-p$. Let them be $p_1, p_2... p_n$.

Thus we can write

$$k+1=p+p_1+p_2+...+p_n$$

which concludes our proof.

---

Is the proof correct? Is there a better way to do it? I have a distinct feeling that it is possible to do this through a proof by *construction*, in which we find the primes through a similar argument.

Edit: My question is not a dupicate because the other question's top answer is not clear enough and only provides a hint. The other answers are not satisfactory.

Further, this is a proof verification question, and my final statement 'can this be proved by a proof by construction' is not addressed in the other question.

Comment: Important is whether $1$ is allowed as a summand. Apparently, it is. Must the primes be distinct ?

Comment: @Peter Yes, it is necessary. Or we can just say $n=1+1+...$

Comment: If we subtract the largest prime smaller than $n$, we get a number not excedding $\frac{n}{2}$. I think we can continue until we arrive at $0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde We cannot write $6$ as a sum of distinct primes (If , as usual , $1$ is not considered to be prime)

Comment: @Peter Yes, you are right. So one should say, every positive integer is a sum of different primes and a single $1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I have edited the question as per your suggestion for clarity.

Comment: It should say "as a sum of distinct primes OR $1$ more than a sum of distinct primes". $2$ is not $1$ more than a sum of primes.

Comment: See also [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382663/prove-that-every-integer-n-geq-7-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-distinct-primes) for a nice proof.

Comment: Can it be shown in some simple way that "Every $n\in \Bbb Z^+$ is a sum of distinct primes or $1$ more than a sum of distinct primes" $ implies$ Bertrand's Postulate (which is actually a theorem) ?