# Expressing any positive number as a sum of distinct primes.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Can every positive integer expressed as a sum of distinct primes? Like 12=5+7, 19=17+2 etc. But there are numbers like 4, 6 which cannot be expressed as a sum of distinct primes. But if we consider 1 as a special number then we can write 4=3+1, 6=3+2+1 or 6=5+1.Is these law applicable for every positive integers? I am confused about this! Can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that every integer $n\geq 7$ can be expressed as a sum of distinct primes.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382663/prove-that-every-integer-n-geq-7-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-distinct-primes). Found in the list of "Related" posts in the right side bar.

Answer (score 2):

Summing two prime numbers always yields an even number because all primes are odd (except 2). So there is no way of getting odd numbers.

Example: Let's try 41. If you use 2 as one of the prime numbers, the next number would be 39 which is not prime. Thus, we cannot write 41 as the sum of two primes.

Your question is related to the [Goldbach Conjecture](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Goldbach_Conjecture#:%7E:text=The%20Goldbach%20Conjecture%20is%20a,and%20in%20all%20of%20mathematics.&text=etc.), an unproven conjecture which asks only about even numbers.

Comment: I don't think the problem limits the sum to two prime numbers. $41=3+7+31$

Comment: Yes. Like 17=7+5+3+2.

Comment: Ah, in that case, let me know if this paper is of any interest to you: https://www.jstor.org/stable/24525178?seq=1